# How to add the auto primary key into django's admin list_display

Tags: django, django-admin, primary-key

Is it possible to include the automatically created primary key into the list_display of the admin site?
I might also need to include that primary key into the links field on the display page.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The automatically created primary key field works just like any other field, except that you don't have to specify it. Unless you've changed the name, this should be as simple as:

```
list_display = ['id', ...]
```

I haven't checked on whether or not the `pk` alias works everywhere that the admin expects field names.
UPDATE: the `pk` alias is accepted instead of `id`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in the [`list_display` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), you can add the `pk` field.

To make it linkable, you can use the [`list_display_links` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'name', 'email', ...) #You can use 'pk' or 'id'
    list_display_links = ('pk', )   #the same here - 'pk' or 'id'

admin.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: I was using both id and pk but not quoted: `list_display(id, ..)` which is wrong ... Thanks both karthik and Peter

Comment: karthir, I couldn't mark it as accepted because both answers (yours and Peter's) are accepted. It seems it is not allowed to mark two answers as accepted.

Comment: I understand that. It is a very common scenario in stackoverflow. Read the link I posted in the comment. It addresses that issue. The idea is not to accept my answer or his. The idea is to mark an answer as accepted so that it is marked as resolved and could be useful for future users